# How can i evaluate the product?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, products

I have to evaluate the following product:

$$\prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(n^3+3n)^2}{n^6-64} $$

But I couldn't develop anything. I thought about breaking the product into smaller parts with some factoring, but I couldn't calculate those products.

Comment: The answer is 72/7.

Comment: Some **hints**:
$$\frac{(n^3+3n)^2}{n^6-64} = \frac{n}{n-2}\cdot \frac n{n+2}\cdot \frac{n^2+3}{(n+1)^2+3}\cdot\frac{n^2+3}{(n-1)^2+3}$$
Now think of telescoping products.

Comment: That was great. I considered $$ \prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(n^3+3n)^2}{n^6-64} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_ {n=3}^{n} \frac{(n^3+3n)^2}{n^6-64} $$ and calculated the telescopic products $$\prod_{n=3}^{n } $$. Then just calculate the limit.